# Pass Controller Data Array to Element for home.ctp

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

According to the manual and my code, this should be working perfect, but it is not. I've been messing around with this code for too long, and I wanted anyone to look at it to see if there is something I cannot see.

I am trying to call the index() action of my plans controller passing an array of data to the element for display. Anyone know why this is not working?

I am getting common error:

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: 
plans [APP/views/elements/search_dental_plans_results.ctp,  line 12]
Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
[APP/views/elements/search_dental_plans_results.ctp, line 12]
```

And here is my code:

*home.ctp*

```
<?php echo $this->element('search_dental_plans_results'); ?>
```

*views/elements/search_dental_plans_results.ctp*

```
<h2>Plans List</h2>
<?php $plans = $this->requestAction('plans/index'); ?>
<?php foreach($plans as $plan): ?>
<ol>
<li><?php echo $plan['Plan']['id']; ?></li>
</ol>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

*controllers/plans_controller.php*

```
function index() {
    //$plans = $this->paginate();
    if (isset($this->params['requested'])) {
        return $plans;
    } else {
        $this->set('plans', $plans);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I SOLVED this in an "unexpected" way (at least according to the manual this method was not noted):

*element*

...

```
$planDetails = $this->requestAction('/planDetails/pd_list');
foreach ($planDetails as $planDetail) :
```

...

*controller logic*

```
function pd_list() {
return $this->PlanDetail->find('all');
}
```

Works like a charm : ) although I am going to use a containable and cache control when done, but at least its working as expected.

Not too holy and problem solved : )

Answer (score 1):

A quick test to see if it is just syntax, but try prepending a forward slash in the 'requestAction' function.

```
<?php $plans = $this->requestAction('/plans/index'); ?>
// @see - http://book.cakephp.org/view/434/requestAction
```

Also, just commenting on the appropriateness of using requestAction, I personally like using it to populate pulldowns and checkbox arrays, etc. in elements. It keeps the controller code cleaner by separating out some of the presentation logic, and it makes it easier on the HTML coder.

It works the best on data that does not change often, like a list of plans, but it is important that you cache the query, otherwise it can just kill your performance.

Answer (score 0):

why is plans commented out, and why the isset() in the if? try putting an exit; before the return and see what happens, chances are the requested is set by default but false and your if should be if($this->params['requested']) or if(isset($this->params['requested']) && $this->params['requested'])

i also do not understand why you are using request action for this, you should almost never use requestAction()

Comment: Thanks for the insight. The manual specifically recommends requestAction for this exact reason. I need to display search results in an element from a form that is in the layout, so I though this would be the best method. Will update you after I've messed with it more.

Comment: $this->params['requested'] is not set unless the action is being called through requestAction(), in which case it's set to 1. So checking whether it is set is actually a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you posted, it doesn't look like your problem is being caused by anything in CakePHP.

An undefined variable is one that hasn't been set anywhere before in the code. But if your element has this:

```
<?php $plans = $this->requestAction('plans/index'); ?>
<?php foreach($plans as $plan): ?>
```

it means that $plans is being set.

$this->requestAction() in your example could return anything, or even nothing at all and the $plans variable would still be considered as defined and you wouldn't get the undefined variable notice.

So I'd try looking somewhere else for the problem. Maybe try changing this line:

```
<?php $plans = $this->requestAction('plans/index'); ?>
```

to:

```
<?php $plans = array(1,2,3); ?>
```

And see if that works. Also try checking your syntax. Maybe you've missed an opening or closing tag somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

The purpose of views or elements are not to request data to a controller. It's the controllers that feed views with data.

Now, your index action doesn't do anything. Nothing is ever assigned to $plan, no wonder you get the error message.